# Hg: Unable to find deleted file in previous commit

Tags: git, mercurial

I have a repo with directory `myrepo` containing `f1.txt`.

First I added these files to repo

```
$ hg add
$ hg commit

Then I removed `f1.txt` and created `f2.txt` and made commit again

$ rm f1.txt
$ vim f2.txt # create file here

$ hg add 
$ hg commit
```

Now when I checkout previous commit, I don't see `f1.txt`. Why is that happening?
I guess it can be done like this in git!

Answer (score 2):

When updating (checkout) to the previous commit, you actually forgot to commit the removal of the f2.txt file. As such, you still have **uncommitted changes**, and updating back to the previous changeset does not revert back the f1.txt file.

This is what you probably get on a `status`

```
$ hg status
! f1.txt
```

You would see that the f1.txt was still missing.

Now, to solve the issue, you actually need to commit the removal of the files too. To do this, it is better to use `addremove`, or, to keep the same sample you mentioned:

```
$ hg addremove
$ hg commit

'Then I removed `f1.txt` and created `f2.txt` and made commit again

$ rm f1.txt
$ vim f2.txt # create file here

$ hg addremove
$ hg commit
```

Your repo would then be as you intended it to be.

Another way to get to the proper state when updating to the previous changeset would be to update and clean:

```
hg update -C
```

This removes the uncommitted changes, and f1.txt will be back.